# Fitnesse - How to know the progress of CLI test suites?

Tags: progress-bar, command-line-interface, fitnesse

How can I find out the progress of a suite triggered via CLI?

I tried the verbose option (`-v`) of the CLI but it does not print the progress.

Also, as per http://butunclebob.com/FitNesse.UserGuide.CommandLineTestRunner, TestRunner does print the progress, but the TestRunner is no longer available in fitnesse anymore.

I would like to see either a percentage of completion or a progress bar showing the progress of how many tests / how much percentage is completed . It need not specify the result of the tests, but just if it has completed the execution or not.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly an answer to your question, but maybe this can help you find a solution to what you are trying to achieve: for my dockerized FitNesse runner I created a [main class](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/hsac/fitnesse/junit/JUnitConsoleRunner.java) that starts a [jUnit test case](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-docker/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/hsac/fitnesse/HsacFitNesseSuiteStarter.java) with listeners attached to show progress (and failure/success). The suite to be run is controlled via system properties, so the Java class is always the same.

I use this in a [shell script](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-docker/blob/master/test/runTests.sh) to start my tests with the following command:

`java -cp ${FITNESSE_CP} ${FITNESSE_OPTS} $@ nl.hsac.fitnesse.junit.JUnitConsoleRunner nl.hsac.fitnesse.HsacFitNesseSuiteStarter`

Comment: This seems promising. Let me try it out and get back with any queries.
Thanks @Fried_Hoeben.